# datatype conflicts in PRO*C and C++

Tags: c++, oracle-pro-c

I am new to proc and I am using it with C++.

I am able to connect to the database.
But after that when I try to fire a query it gives me error.

CODE:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
   string custName=cusName;
   long int custID=cusID;
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

  EXEC SQL insert into tbl_customer5 values(:custID,:custName)
```

ERROR:

```
   Syntax error at line 42, column 4, file Customer.pc:
    Error at line 42, column 4 in file Customer.pc
       string custName=cusName;
    ...1
    PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "string" when expecting one of the following

:

   auto, char, const, double, enum, extern, float, int, long,
   ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
   OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
   OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
   short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
   typedef, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name, a precompiled header, exec oracle,
   exec oracle begin, exec, exec sql, exec sql begin,
   exec sql end, exec sql type, exec sql var, exec sql include,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "string" to continue.
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error.
Can we use data equivalency in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use OCCI instead of ProC when using C++?

Comment: @nabulke:  Last place I used OCCI in, I loved it, but it was only available in binary, and only for some compilers, so it greatly restricted our software choices.  For example, it was only available for Sun C++ with the older non-standard STL.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, the "string" symbol does not exist. Try to use varchar instead.

Comment: varchar is not defined in c++ 
how can i use varchar then
do i need to apply data equivalency concepts

Comment: PRO*C will handle varchar not C. After its preprocessor execution valid code will be provided to the C compiler

Answer (score 0):

It can't find string.

You may need std:: on the front of it,
or you many need to add include paths to the Pro*C invocation to allow the preprocessor to find the correct include files.
There are other Pro*C options that can effect things.

Can you show us the whole makefile?